# How does ASP.Net know, IsPostBack is true or false?

Tags: asp.net, ispostback

When a page is requested on server and response is sent back to the client, we tend to understand that a request/response relation exists between client and server where for every request a new request/response gets generated, than how does the server know, that IsPostBack is true/false on first or subsequent request?

Comment: Requests have types. When you request a page you send a GET. When you clikc a button, ie submit a form, you send a POST.

Comment: Alright, I get it, I would want to mark your answer as the correct one.